# java.net.BindException: Address already in use /127.0.0.1:13444

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

Galera, tenho uma aplicação rodando no intagrator e hoje o sistema caiu, vendo os logs me deparei com esse erro:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use /127.0.0.1:13444
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:413)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:649)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:403)
... 17 more
```

É problema com o banco de dados?

Answer (score 1):

Esse problema acontece porque o tomcat (ou algum outro programa) já está rodando na porta 13444 e uma segunda instância do tomcat começou a rodar também na porta 13444. Cada porta TCP só pode ser usada por um processo por vez. Desta forma, esse segundo tomcat falhou.

Assim sendo, verifique o procedimento que inicia a execução do tomcat para se certificar que você não tenta executá-lo duas vezes na mesma porta.

Por fim, pode ter certeza que o problema não é o banco de dados.